# React Child and Parent Components state change on click

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a click on a button of a child React component change the Boolean state of the child and of its parent.
The issue here is that it has to change states of both components.

Here is a link for the code I am trying to get working:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-to-parent-state-pass-bkmvwc?file=Child.js

The requirement is to click the hamburger button and it changes the state of the child component (the actual hamburger button) and its parent component.

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably copy the code into the question. That being said `handleCounter()` in component `Parent`/`NavBar` will error when trying to evaluate `this.state.opened` as you have not bound the function. https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-to-parent-state-pass-r5yqng

Comment: See https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-to-parent-state-pass-e6qduq although the better approach would be to keep the state of the burger at the topmost component you need and pass it down as props to all the others that need to know.

Comment: For the better approach see https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-to-parent-state-pass-kdqqb5

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing what you are doing.
But, knowing nothing of your background I will only answer your question.

In parent.js you are missing the bind to this. 
Use this line instead and check if this works

Answer (score 0):

You would only change the state of the parent.  The child would just read the props that are passed to it.

**Parent component**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    hamburgerOpen: false
  }
}

handleHamburgerToggle = () => {
  let { hamburgerOpen } = this.state;
  this.setState({
     hamburgerOpen: !hamburgerOpen
  })
}

render() {
  let { hamburgerOpen } = this.state;

  return (
     <Child
       hamburgerOpen={hamburgerOpen}
       handleHamburgerToggle={this.handleHamburgerToggle}
     />
  )
}
```

Child will have access to the props passed to it.  You can make the Hamburger a functional component as well since it isn't concerned about the current state, only the parent is.

hamburgerOpen and toggleHamburgerOpen

**Child Component**

```
const { handleHamburgerToggle } = this.props;
return {
  <div>
    <div
      onClick={() => handleHamburgerToggle()}
    >
    Click me to toggle hamburger
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I like your code but it seems like something is not working with the line:   
    let { hamburgerOpen } = this.state;   I updates the snipped here      https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-to-parent-state-pass-najyf5?file=Parent.js   Thanks!

Comment: Ah.  I was using colons instead of equal signs.  I updated to match.  It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you manage the state from the parent component [like](https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-to-parent-state-pass-xpbysf):

**Parent.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { initializeIcons } from '@uifabric/icons';
import Hamburger from './Child'
initializeIcons();

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opened: false
     };
  }
  handleCounter = () => {
    this.setState({ opened: !this.state.opened });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Hamburger 
          opened={this.state.opened} 
          handleCounter={this.handleCounter}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

**Child.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { IconButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { initializeIcons } from '@uifabric/icons';
initializeIcons();


export default class Hamburger extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  updateParent() {
    this.props.handleCounter(this.state);
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <IconButton
        checked={this.props.opened}
        iconProps={{ iconName: (this.props.opened ? 'Cancel' : 'GlobalNavButton'), style: { fontSize: 35 } }} 
        className="hamburger mobile-only"
        title="Open Global Navigation" 
        ariaLabel="Open Global Navigation"
        styles={{
          root: {
            padding: '0',
            border: 'none',
            background: 'transparent !important'
          }
        }}
        onClick={this.props.handleCounter}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

PS: I removed the comments for readability

Comment: Is not `checked={this.props.handleCounter}` in the checked but `checked={this.props.opened}`

Comment: Thanks yes I guess that's the right way but Ive been trying that and couldn't get it working, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes sorry I just saw the link you provided to the changes which is working perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: btw if your `Hamburger` component is not going to manage state then make it a functional component. And please mark my answer as the correct one (if so :D).